# Placeholders are not generated for search forms after updating YiiBooster from 2.0.0

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, updating, twitter-bootstrap-2

We were generating CRUDs using Bootstrap Generator and on views/user/_search.php, earlier we used

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
  'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
  'method'=>'get',
  'type'=>'inline',
));
?>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'firstName', array('class'=>'span12')); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

But after updating YiiBooster 2.0.0 to latest version, all auto generated placeholders on search forms were disappeared from the system and and also Block level inputs were resized.

after updating 'type'=>'inline' to 'type'=>'search' we could get Block level inputs again, but not auto generated placeholders. Is there anyway to enable auto generated placeholders on search forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use bootstrap 2, please upgrade to v3.0.1 or any later 3.x.x

if you want the latest bootstrap 3, please use the latest v4.0.0 or later